# Gregorian Calendar starting day of the week Tuesday instead of Sunday

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

I am using GregorianCalendar as it follows

new GregorianCalendar(1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 1)

and returns a date starting from Tuesday.

Is there any way to configure it in order to return as first day of the week the 'Sunday'.

I want to return a Calendar object.

I used the following solution

```
switch (gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {    
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);    
            break;  
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:  
            gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -2);  
            break;  
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:  
            gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -3);  
            break;  
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:  
            gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -4);  
            break;  
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:  
            gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -5);  
            break;  
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:    
            gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -6);  
            break;  
    }
```

I don't know if its the best one.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. For `new GregorianCalendar(1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 1)` I get Monday `Mon, 1 Jan 1900` not Tuesday. Furthermore, `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))` depends on the date. It's not the same for all weeks. I don't get it. Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Tuesday was a random result..After the initialization of the gregorian calendar, I set an integer that I want to transform to a date. And I was wondering how to configure the date in order to return the Sunday as the day returned and not another day. Is this more clear to you?

Comment: Not at all. Where is the Integer you mention in the question? How do you set this Integer? Edit your question and post _relevant_ code. What represents this Integer? It's a Timestamp? A random value?
If you just want to set the day of a calendar on SUNDAY: `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);`

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are looking for previous Sunday ?
Then I would rather do something like:

`while (gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
    gregorianCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);
}`

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 23 )
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) )
```

## java.time

The modern way to determine the date of a previous day-of-week is with the java.time classes. The old date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar` are now legacy, obsolete.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The `TemporalAdjuster` interface provides a way to determine other dates from one date. Implementations we need are found in the `TemporalAdjusters` class (note plural).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) ;
LocalDate previousSunday = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ) ;
```

If you are trying to represent a week as a collection of day-of-week values in a particular order, use an `EnumSet` with `DayOfWeek` enum objects.

```
EnumSet<DayOfWeek> dows = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY , DayOfWeek.MONDAY , … ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).